# Active and passive transformations and the change in potential energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, coordinate-systems

Under [active transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation), the particle moves. On the other hand, for a passive one, the coordinate is just relabel.

I've read that the passive one will not affect the potential energy and the active one will change it. This is the case for two massively different size objects, like earth and a ball. But basically there will be no difference between passive and active transformation if the two objects making the system are comparable in size.

My question is how to prove that and which mathematical framework one should use?

Comment: Active transformations change the placements of objects in space independently of the observer. Passive transformations change only the placement of the observer and leave the objects in space untouched. Why do you think that there is no difference between active and passive transformations when two objects are comparable in size?

Comment: acccording to Leonard Susskind it's so, I'am trying to figure why !

Comment: Hm, maybe this comes from particle physics where there is no observation without influencing the system? In this context the ball itself would **be** the observer. But, that is not my field. Sorry.